# How to animate back an UITableView on keyboard hide?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uitextfield

I have an UItextField in the last cell of the UITableView.
My code to handle keyboard hiding :

```
func keyboardWillBeHidden(aNotification:NSNotification) {
      let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
      tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
      tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

Works perfectly on iOS8 with a smooth animation.
Moves back to its original position brutally on iOS7 (no animation) !

What's the solution on iOS7 ?

Comment: Have you tried putting everything into an animation block?

Comment: Try putting your code in a UIView.
+ animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this first. Adjust the animation duration to your preference.

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
            let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
            self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
            self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before. Its in objective c. Check this -

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)sender
{

    NSTimeInterval duration = [[[sender userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        [_tableView setContentInset:edgeInsets];
        [_tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:edgeInsets];
    }];
}
```